# How to get protobuf enum as string?

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to obtain the string equivalent of protobuf enums in C++?

e.g.:

***The following is the message description:***

```
package MyPackage;

message MyMessage
{
    enum RequestType
    {
        Login = 0;
        Logout = 1;
    }

    optional RequestType requestType = 1;
}
```

***In my code I wish to do something like this:***

```
MyMessage::RequestType requestType = MyMessage::RequestType::Login;

// requestTypeString will be "Login"
std::string requestTypeString = ProtobufEnumToString(requestType);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [EnumDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumDescriptor) and [EnumValueDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumValueDescriptor) classes can be used for this kind of manipulation, and the 
the generated `.pb.h` and `.pb.cc` names are easy enough to read, so you can look through them to get details on the functions they offer.

In this particular case, the following should work (untested):

```
std::string requestTypeString = MyMessage_RequestType_Name(requestType);
```

Comment: Small nitpick: The protobuf doc recommends not to use the global functions with mangled names, but instead the class scoped functions, so instead of `MyMessage_RequestType_Name`, use `MyMessage::RequestType_Name`.

Answer (score 22):

See the answer of [Josh Kelley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25507/josh-kelley), use the [EnumDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumDescriptor) and [EnumValueDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#EnumValueDescriptor).

The EnumDescriptor documentation says:

- To get a EnumDescriptor

  > To get the EnumDescriptor for a generated enum type, call
  >   TypeName_descriptor(). Use DescriptorPool to construct your own
  >   descriptors.
- To get the string value, use FindValueByNumber(int number)

  > const EnumValueDescriptor * EnumDescriptor::FindValueByNumber(int number) const
  >
  > Looks up a value by number.
  >
  > Returns NULL if no such value exists. If multiple values have this >number,the first one defined is returned.

Example, get the protobuf enum:

```
enum UserStatus {
  AWAY = 0;
  ONLINE = 1;
  OFFLINE = 2;
}
```

The code to read the string name from a value and the value from a string name:

```
const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor *descriptor = UserStatus_descriptor();

std::string name = descriptor->FindValueByNumber(UserStatus::ONLINE)->name();
int number = descriptor->FindValueByName("ONLINE")->number();

std::cout << "Enum name: " << name << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enum number: " << number << std::endl;
```

Comment: Watch the `->name()` and `->number()` at the end of those examples.  They can be easy to miss and hard to figure out how to get them corrected.