# C++: Simplifiying a #define

Tags: c++, variadic, define-syntax

I have a #define with generates a enum class and a corresponding output operator the the generated enum class.(see below)

```
#define ENUM(N, T, N1, V1, N2, V2, N3, V3, N4, V4, N5, V5, N6, V6, N7, V7)\
    enum class N : T {\
        N1 = V1,\
        N2 = V2,\
        N3 = V3,\
        N4 = V4,\
        N5 = V5,\
        N6 = V6,\
        N7 = V7,\
    };\
    std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const N val);   /* declare function to avoid compiler warning */\
    std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const N val) {\
        switch (val) {\
        case N::N1:\
            os << #N1;\
            break;\
        case N::N2:\
            os << #N2;\
            break;\
        case N::N3:\
            os << #N3;\
            break;\
        case N::N4:\
            os << #N4;\
            break;\
        case N::N5:\
            os << #N5;\
            break;\
        case N::N6:\
            os << #N6;\
            break;\
        case N::N7:\
            os << #N7;\
            break;\
        }\
        if (sizeof(T) == 1) {\
            os << '(' << static_cast<int>(val) << ')';\
        } else {\
            os << '(' << static_cast<T>(val) << ')';\
        }\
        return os;\
    }
```

It can be used like here in this example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

ENUM(Weekdays, unsigned char, Monday, 10, Tuesday, 12, Wednesday, 14, Thursday, 16, Friday, 18, Saterday, 100, Sunday, 101)

int main(const int /*argc*/, const char *const /*argv*/[]) {
    Weekdays    test    = Weekdays::Monday;

    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Tuesday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Sunday << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

here the generated output:

```
Monday(10)
Tuesday(12)
Sunday(101)
```

My solution has some restrictions:

- each enumeration needs an initialization value
- fixed to 7 enumeration values

For a more generalized usage I have two questions. Especially the second one would increase the usability enormously.

Any here my questions:

1. How can I avoid to define a initialization value for each enumeration value?
   (like in a real enumeration)
2. Any ideas to generalize the #define to work with any number of values?

I'm waiting for your comments to my code and suggestions for improvement.
Rainer

Comment: You’re writing C++, so why aren’t you using templates?

Comment: @Dai Converting enum to string with templates is fairly obscure.

Comment: can be done with X macros

Comment: @Dai I not very familiar with templates. I've no idea how to realize this with templates, nor solve my problems with templates.
If you can, show us how!

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html will probably be helpful

Comment: For complex stuff like this, I would personally choose to use "proper" meta programming rather than macro meta programming. So, I recommend considering that option at least.

Comment: @Alan Birtles Can you convert the example to BOOST, including my additional requested features?

Comment: @Rainer I think you want a variadic template: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996403/build-an-enum-using-variadic-template-parameters

Comment: @eeroika What do you mean with "proper" meta programming? Manually coding the features a each enumeration?
I like the macro because I can use it to define very simply new numerations and corresponding output operators.(if a copy/paste/adapt the macro for enumerations with another number of values.

Comment: @eerorika What constitutes “proper” metaprogramming in your opinion?

Comment: @Dai Write a program that writes a program.

Comment: @Dai There is no tautology. You write a program. That program writes another program for you.

Comment: @eerorika C++ Templates a Turing-complete programs in themselves. What about T4 Templates? LinqPad? And C-preprocessor macros are still “programs” that generate code, even if they have limits to their expressiveness. I argue that *all* meta-programming is “proper” metaprogramming. No program is “improper” if it works (unless you’re a stickler for nonfunctional testing…), therefore no metaprogram is “improper” either.

Comment: @Dai Why choose a "language" that has limited expressiveness when there is a world of more powerful languages available?

Comment: @Dai I would argue that c++ macros and templates are part of the language itself, and thus don't constitute as "proper" meta programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking relatively close what you have right now, you can take advantage of the BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH macro from Boost.Preprocessor, which could look something like this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define ENUM_FIELD(I,_,F) F,
#define ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE(I,N,F) case N::F: os << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(F); break;

#define ENUM(N, T, ARGS) \
enum class N : T {\
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ENUM_FIELD,N,ARGS)\
};\
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const N val) {\
    switch (val) {\
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE,N,ARGS)\
    }\
    \
    os << '(' << static_cast<int>(val) << ')';\
    return os;\
}

ENUM(Weekdays, unsigned char, (Monday)(Tuesday)(Wednesday)(Thursday)(Friday)(Saturday)(Sunday))
```

That removes both the duplication and possibility of supplying the values. The whole thing is shorter, arguably at the cost of making it less readable and potentially harder to debug – I won't weigh in on the pro's and cons of using macros like these.

Note that I've changed the way arguments are passed to the ENUM macro: this is now a Boost.Preprocessor *sequence*. You should be able to pass up to 256 elements; see the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/) for more information and more macros that work on sequences.

Comment: Nice solution.
When I understood your comment it is not possible to define initial value for the enumerations. But this is essential for me because some of my enumerations have gaps.

Comment: Ah, right - I thought that you didn't want to provide values at all. You could adapt the above to pass a sequence of day name/value tuples rather than a sequence of day names, and then use `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM` to pull either part out again... though note that this stuff tends to turn into spaghetti fairly quickly.

Comment: I make it. Replace two lines:
#define ENUM_FIELD(I,_,F) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)=BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,F),
#define ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE(I,N,F) case N::BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F): os << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)); break;

Comment: Is it possible to combile the two solutions?
Like if number of Arguments in tuple is 1 than do older solution, if number of Arguments in tuple is 2 than to new solution.
For ENUM_FIELD and for ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE

Comment: Yep, that should be possible. You can ask for BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE and then choose between macros based on that.

Comment: Can you show me at one of them how to use  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE inside of a macro. (e.g. ENUM_FIELD)

Comment: Here the code for ENUM_FIELD to enable optional definition of values.
#define ENUM_FIELD(I,_,F)\
 BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_EQUAL(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(F),2),\
     BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)=BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,F),\
     BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)),

Answer (score 1):

I made it working for me. Some special features have been added:

- manipulator to switch on/off outputting the value of the enums
  (in brackets behind the enum)
- output for illegal value
  (should not happen: see code for possible occurence)

Here my complete solution:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>

class EnumShowValue {
private:
    static bool showValueFlag;
public:
    explicit EnumShowValue(const bool flag) { EnumShowValue::showValueFlag  = flag; }

    static bool showValue() { return EnumShowValue::showValueFlag; }
};
bool    EnumShowValue::showValueFlag    = false;

inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const EnumShowValue &) { return os; }

#define ENUM_FIELD(I,_,F)\
    BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_EQUAL(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(F),2),\
                    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)=BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,F),\
                    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F)),

#define ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE(I,N,F)\
    case N::BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F):\
        os << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,F));\
        break;

#define ENUM(N, T, ARGS) \
enum class N : T {\
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ENUM_FIELD,N,ARGS)\
};\
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const N val);\
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const N val) {\
    switch (val) {\
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ENUM_OUTPUT_CASE,N,ARGS)\
    default:\
        os << "illegal value: " << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(N);\
        if (!EnumShowValue::showValue()) {\
            os << '(';\
            if (sizeof(T) == 1) {\
                os << static_cast<int>(val);\
            } else {\
                os << static_cast<T>(val);\
            }\
            os << ')';\
        }\
    }\
    if (EnumShowValue::showValue()) {\
                    os << '(';\
                    if (sizeof(T) == 1) {\
                        os << static_cast<int>(val);\
                    } else {\
                        os << static_cast<T>(val);\
                    }\
                    os << ')';\
    }\
    return os;\
}

ENUM(Weekdays, unsigned char, ((Monday, 101))((Tuesday))((Wednesday))((Thursday))((Friday))((Saturday, 200))((Sunday)))

int main(const int /*argc*/, const char *const /*argv*/[]) {

    std::cout << Weekdays::Monday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Tuesday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Wednesday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Thursday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Friday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Saturday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Sunday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays(99) << std::endl;

    std::cout << EnumShowValue(true);
    std::cout << Weekdays::Monday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Tuesday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Wednesday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Thursday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Friday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays::Saturday << std::endl;
    std::cout << EnumShowValue(false);
    std::cout << Weekdays::Sunday << std::endl;
    std::cout << Weekdays(-1) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the corresponding output:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
illegal value: Weekdays(99)
Monday(101)
Tuesday(102)
Wednesday(103)
Thursday(104)
Friday(105)
Saturday(200)
Sunday
illegal value: Weekdays(255)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to know this compile time you could use a library like Protobuf to define your enums in. Protobuf in C++ supports Enum Descriptors which can be used as a form of reflections. These two posts describe possible solutions with Protobuf ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161409/how-to-get-protobuf-enum-as-string) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571289/get-enum-values-using-reflection-google-protobuf)).

Edit:
I forgot there is another library that might be of use to you if yo need it compile time. It is called [Frozen](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen) and provides compile time maps. You might be able to generate some code defining the map and use it to convert enum values to strings.